# How to handle version of files in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, single-page-application, systemjs

In current angular app 1.x, I use a custom module and file loader, which allow me adding a suffix(v=x.y) to file url. Browser will base on that suffix to load file from cache or take it from server. Such as:

```
'app/user/user.services.js?v=1.2',
'app/order/order.services.js?v=1.3',
```

Version numbers(1.2, 1.3...) is set dynamically in each user session by my loader, version number for each file can be different.

On angular 2, with SystemJs, **how can I define version number for files imported by SystemJs** used in my app.

Suggesting me **some other loaders** to solve this case is highly appreciated!

Comment: you are trying to solve cache problem of browser ? using reversioning of files ?

Comment: Yes, I want browser use cached file before requesting server for that  files with systemjs in angular 2

Comment: okay so to achieve this you can use gulp tasks, by doing so it will Append hashcode by default in your file url, which is used to remove the problem of cache of browsers. i dont know about systemJs loader or any thing related to that.

Comment: No, version number must be append dynamiccally to url of file at the start time of user session

Comment: hmm exactly version no. updated automatically. if required ill post as answer using gulp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working a round, I found a solution for this.
Before running system.config.js, I will load a version number from server by a request. And we have a version number for app at start time.

```
var vQuery = '?v=1.3';
```

Then I can added a prefix to every request by config package in systemjs. It is just by **adding a prefix to value of defaultExtension**

```
packages: {
  app: {
      main: './main',
      defaultExtension: 'ts' + vQuery
  }
}
```

After that, when SystemJS load a file, it will automatically add a prefix(?v=1.3) to file url such as:

```
/src/components/todoList.ts?v=1.3
/src/components/newTodo.ts?v=1.3
```

We can also add **a different version number for each package** by generating a config for each package and add it dynamically to SystemJS. Config code as below:

```
var ngPackageNames = ['all','of your','packages'];

// list of configs for each package
var packages = [];

//method to find version for each package
getVersionOfFile: function(package){
    // find version of package and return
    return 'v=' + 'version of this package';
}

// generate config
ngPackageNames.forEach(function(package){
   // handle config for this package
   packages[pkgName] = { main: packageFile, defaultExtension: 'ts' +  getVersionOfFile(package) };
});

// at last, add config for all packages to SystemJS
var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
}

System.config(config);
```

Comment: Hello @VuQuyet, "I will load a version number from server by a request" how do you do that ? Where do you keep this version ? thx

Comment: Just keep a json file with version number like { "version": "0.0.1" }, then request version with $http.get(versionUrl)

Answer (score 0):

This should be done at build time -- using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev-replace

I would recommend using file hashes to version your files -- as it will only cause files that have actually changed to be recached in the browser.

Comment: Can you talk more detail about the way we will use gulp-rev and gulp-rev-replace to process import commands or configuration phase of SystemJs?